# Are there any resources listing current codecs and formats not supported by FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, transcoding

We are building a service where we do not know what format/codec a video uploaded by a user is in. Due to the nature of the application, we expect input video formats to be very fragmented, diverse and niche. We are currently using FFmpeg to transcode input formats to a consistent output (e.g. mp4).

Due to the above scenario, I would like to establish a general list of what formats and codecs are not currently supported by FFmpeg. This is so I can research other open source video transcoding tools which I can utilise to fill in the gaps and allow our service to be more reliable for the user.

Are there resources online that can help at least get a general idea of what might not be supported by FFmpeg?

Comment: So, you want `all codecs ever invented minus those ffmpeg-supported`. Too broad.

Comment: In practice, these will be proprietary or obscure, so not supported by a FOSS tool.

Comment: If you are aware of any formats that users have asked you to support which aren't yet, and this is listed somewhere, then that is exactly the kind of thing I am looking for.

Comment: I'm just looking for a general idea. There might be well known formats not supported by ffmpeg utilised by cctv which are listed somewhere for instance. I did my best to carefully word and consider the above question's body, so I was hoping it was obvious I wasn't asking that. Feel free to edit the question to something more suitable if you don't agree. And thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: 1) Many of the CCTV / LEO / forensic codecs which typically are modified versions of standard bitstreams or with their own flavor of encapsulation. AMPED FIVE is used by many to convert these. Similar holds for video conferencing / telephony services. 2) Proprietary bitstreams developed to store game assets or recorded gameplay.

Comment: Ah yes, I came across AMPED at a technology roadshow. It's interesting you've mentioned them. It might be the answer to the question is it's too broad to try to research and list unsupported formats as these could be wide and everchanging. Also suggestions as you've made here in regards to options could be added to that. If you also think that a suitable answer to this, then formally answer below and happy to give you a green tick :)

Comment: I or someone could try to pick the low-hanging fruit if we knew what niche or target audience your service is aimed at. e.g. broadcast professionals will present different files than gamers.

Comment: I can't really say unfortunately. But what I can say is the file format would most likely be CCTV which we then need to convert into an mp4 file. The latter as this is the required format we need to then pass it on for processing by a 3rd party API. We've handled the complexities of length in time, fps, resolution etc, just the unknown of formats was something I was researching really. I'm pretty sure I talked to the AMPED team and they said their product triages footage with FFmpeg, MEncoder and VLC. But then again, the person I was talking to might not have know what they were talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there resources online that can help at least get a general idea of what might not be supported by FFmpeg?

You'll have to trawl the [FFmpeg bug tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/). You are probably looking for a more in-depth answer, but we don't have an official list of currently unsupported formats (including formats that we may not even be aware of).

If you encounter anything unsupported a bug report and samples are always appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and it's good to know that I can feedback and assist towards FFmpeg this way too. I already have a list of unsupported extensions I have come across so happy to raise as a bug report. I didn't think it an unreasonable question to ask as it was more asking for guidance rather than a concrete definitive answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderSwann Just search first before submitting a bug report/feature request. There may already be a similar one since there are thousands already. You will be asked for your command and the complete log if you don't include it, so provide those. And only the git master branch is supported (because releases are not as current and could be missing bug fixes and features), so compile or download a recent build before submitting a report.

Comment: I've also reworded the question to make it clear I'm not asking 'gimme all unsupported formats'. I was trying to keep it simple with a more in-depth explanation below it. But obviously failed as those downvoting clearly didn't read the latter (◔_◔). I've never been a particularly great content designer.